# How to model Bishop movement on a chessboard

Tags: python, chess

I have a board, and I want to model a bishop's possible moves on it. I attempted this code:

```
for c1, c2 in [(1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, -1), (-1, 1)]:
    for x, y in [range(x+c1, board_size), range(y+c2, board_size)]:
        moves.append(x, y)
```

But it doesn't work to find all the moves. Yet, I don't understand why. Doesn't it check all four directions?

Comment: You're missing a `]`.

Comment: Also, use `zip` instead of making a list of two elements.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect `moves` to contain after this loop has been executed. Can you give an expected example result for a small board size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is sound, but your execution is not.

1. Half of your calculations must go from `x` or `y` to 0 (the other half go from `x` or `y` to `board_size`
2. Ranges don't work from larger to smaller values with the default step, so you'll need to introduce a step of -1 to count from `x` or `y` to 0
3. You should use `zip()` to create an iterable collection of tuples.

This will work:

```
right_up = zip(range(x + 1, board_size), range(y - 1, -1, -1))
right_down = zip(range(x + 1, board_size), range(y + 1, board_size)) 

left_up = zip(range(x - 1, -1, -1), range(y - 1, -1, -1))
left_down = zip(range(x - 1, -1, -1), range(y + 1, board_size))

for r in (right_up, right_down, left_up, left_down):
    for new_x, new_y in r:  # add coordinates to move list
```

Comment: Can you clarify what `Config` is? I'm assuming `Config.b_len` is supposed to be OP's `board_size`? Is there a reason for indenting the loops and leaving out the actual assignment?

Comment: No reason, just poor formatting that I fixed. I left out the assignment because he can choose how or what to append. Setting board coordinates is board[y][x], not board[x][y], for example.